# Using the Volume of Sales obtained today to predict volume of Sales at the Event

Tags: r, time-series, predictive-models, modeling, multivariate-regression

I wonder if anyone can help.

I have a set of data on event ticket sales. I have information on eventdate,  location, capacity, cumulative sales, sales date, total sales.

I want to be able to build a model which takes a minimum input of The number of tickets currently sold and days until the event and it would return a value for predicted total tickets sold.

I think I need to use a time-series model or a Survival model, but I am unsure how structure my data and construct it in this instance.

Does anyone have any, tips/pointers/guidance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the capacity of the event, you could model the probability that the accumulated sale of the event will reach 100%. That is, sample the cumulative sale of tickets per event and choose the probability distribution that best characterizes the time random variable (exponential, gamma, weibull). I recommend you to read the following article: [Forecasting Event Ticket Sales (Suher,2008)](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1048&context=wharton_research_scholars)

I regret the lateness of my answer, but there are similar questions in the forum 
 ([search: ticket sales](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ticket+sales)), however yours summarizes quite a lot the information that is generally available.